# Cannot change video quality in youtube iframe

Tags: video, embed, youtube-iframe-api

i've been struggling with the youtube iframe api with the intention to force the quality settings of an embbeded video.

I've seen some old responses here at stack overflow but since their demo page also fails:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

And their support page redirects you here...